# Managed metadata Service Application Connections - Some clarification

Tags: managed-metadata, web-application, managed-metadata-service

When we create a new "Managed Metadata service" Application through Central administration, It automatically goes to Default "Application Proxy Group" (unless we specify otherwise) right? All the web applications that are members to this Default "Application Proxy Group" will automatically be associated to this newly created Managed Metadata Service, is that correct ?

When we create a new "Managed Metadata Service" application by using PowerShell, it does not go to any Application proxy group including default group, is that correct ? If its correct, then it means no web application will be automatically associated to this new MMS, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That's correct, when you create from central admin it give an option at the end of page which application proxy group you want to add it. Once you select and if that proxy group(lets say default) associated with any web app can consume the service.
2. When you use PowerShell you have to run extra script line to add it to the proxy group otherwise service application will get created but no association.
3. If MMS is created but not part of any proxy group then no one can use it.

   ```
   New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name ManagedMetaDataAppPool -Account contoso\managedmetadata_svc

   New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name "MetadataServiceApp" -ApplicationPool "ManagedMetaDataAppPool" -DatabaseName "MetadataDB"

   New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Name "MetadataServiceProxy" -ServiceApplication "POFPROD_MetadataServiceApp" -DefaultProxyGroup
   ```

http://sp-vinod.blogspot.com/2013/02/create-managed-metadata-service.html